# Unity: how intercept Mouse Click on UI and not fire "shoot"?

Tags: unity, c#

I've a classic

```
void Update() {
   if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
      Fire();
}
```

What i want to do is that if I click on a UI button , the `Fire()` routine not will be called.

How to do to say Unity `if InputGetMouseButtonDown(0) && !UI clicked` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, first, stop using `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`, use `Input.GetButton("Fire1")`. This allows your player to remap the controls. It won't fix your problem, but this is still something you should do.

Onto your problem, you have a few options:

- When the UI is up, set some global variable (eg. `gamePaused`) that when true, your game logic doesn't execute. This includes shooting.
- Ask the event system: `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()`
- Check if your mouse is in a region of the screen (eg. over/not over the UI) and if over the UI, don't fire.

Comment: First, Thanks for your answer. I'm trying with EventSystemManager.currentSystem.IsPointerOverEventSystemObject() but it seems it didn't recognize. Do I need to add "using" something ? I've also added "using UnityEngine.EventSystems" but not works

Comment: @stighy Sorry, old code. You do need a using (`using UnityEngine.EventSystems`), but the *current* method call is `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()`, it's been renamed at least once if not twice.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that when you click on the UI button, you should enable / disable the script that has the Fire().